# How can I add a command to the Python interactive shell?

Tags: python, interactive, readline, cpython

I'm trying to save myself just a few keystrokes for a command I type fairly regularly in Python.

In my [python startup script](http://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONSTARTUP), I define a function called load which is similar to import, but adds some functionality.  It takes a single string:

```
def load(s):
  # Do some stuff
  return something
```

In order to call this function I have to type

```
>>> load('something')
```

I would rather be able to simply type:

```
>>> load something
```

I am running Python with [readline](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/readline.html) support, so I know there exists some programmability there, but I don't know if this sort of thing is possible using it.

I attempted to get around this by using the `InteractivConsole` and creating an instance of it in my startup file, like so:

```
import code, re, traceback

class LoadingInteractiveConsole(code.InteractiveConsole):
  def raw_input(self, prompt = ""):
    s = raw_input(prompt)
    match = re.match('^load\s+(.+)', s)
    if match:
      module = match.group(1)
      try:
        load(module)
        print "Loaded " + module
      except ImportError:
        traceback.print_exc()
      return ''
    else:
      return s

console = LoadingInteractiveConsole()
console.interact("")
```

This works with the caveat that I have to hit Ctrl-D twice to exit the python interpreter: once to get out of my custom console, once to get out of the real one.

Is there a way to do this without writing a custom C program and embedding the interpreter into it?

### Edit

Out of channel, I had the suggestion of appending this to the end of my startup file:

```
import sys
sys.exit()
```

It works well enough, but I'm still interested in alternative solutions.

Comment: Have you considered adding an API to your website so that I can check for global annihilation due to the LHC and actively update my blog with the status?

Comment: @orokusaki If only that site were actively maintained by me, I would add it to the extensive feature request list.  Alas, I merely find the site amusing and the non-trivial detection script just this side of heaven.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hate to answer my own question, but there hasn't been an answer that works for all the versions of Python I use.  Aside from the solution I posted in my question edit (which is what I'm now using), here's another:

Edit `.bashrc` to contain the following lines:

```
alias python3='python3 ~/py/shellreplace.py'
alias python='python ~/py/shellreplace.py'
alias python27='python27 ~/py/shellreplace.py'
```

Then simply move all of the `LoadingInteractiveConsole` code into the file `~/py/shellreplace.py`  Once the script finishes executing, python will cease executing, and the improved interactive session will be seamless.

Answer (score 7):

You could try [ipython](http://ipython.scipy.org/moin/) - which gives a python shell which does allow many things including [automatic parentheses](http://ipython.scipy.org/doc/manual/html/interactive/reference.html#automatic-parentheses) which gives you the function call as you requested.

Comment: +1. I think `ipython` gives you some of the features you're looking for.

Comment: From the quick skim I did of the iPython website, I wasn't able to determine which version of Python it implements/wraps.  I have to write code for 2.6/2.7/3 at various times, so I run python, python2.7, python3, and each binary conveniently reads the same startup file.  Is there a way to change the version of Python that iPython uses?  (Pardon me for veering a fair bit off the original question.)

Comment: You can run ipython with various interpreters.  It is not tied to any specific python implementation http://ipython.scipy.org/moin/FAQ (not sure about 3.0 though).

Comment: @Mark: Oh, erp, nm.  [The introduction](http://ipython.scipy.org/doc/manual/html/overview.html) states "works with either Python 2.5 or 2.6...We have not yet begun to test and port IPython to Python 3."  This won't work for me.

Comment: My Comment was wrong.  Ipython is officially only tied to 2.5 or 2.6, but can be used with either.  http://ipython.scipy.org/moin/

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the cmd module.

See a tutorial here:
http://wiki.python.org/moin/CmdModule

Comment: I do not.  I want to type "python" and have the normal shell with a small amount of extension.

Comment: To be clear, the cmd modules is designed to make an entirely new interactive shell.  Even if I were to implement an entirely new shell into it, I would have the same capabilities (and problem) that I have with the solution I posted in my question.

Comment: Apologies.  Should have read your question a little bit closer.